# Any method for finding the combination of a word?

Tags: groovy

I want to find the all possible combination of a given word. For example say, the given word is "the" then I need "t,h,e,teh..". I have to find this in groovy, is there is any method? Or please say me the outline of the algorithm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need subsets as well, you could do something like this:

```
("word" as List).subsequences()*.permutations().inject( [] ) { list, set ->
  list.addAll( set )
  list
}*.join().sort { it.length() }
```

which gives you the following output:

> [o, d, r, w, dw, wd, do, od, dr, rd,
>   wr, rw, ow, wo, ro, or, owd, wod, wdo,
>   odw, dwo, dow, orw, owr, wor, wro,
>   rwo, row, dor, ord, odr, rdo, rod,
>   dro, wdr, rwd, drw, rdw, wrd, dwr,
>   wrdo, orwd, wrod, wodr, ordw, wdor,
>   rwod, wdro, word, owdr, rdow, drow,
>   drwo, rdwo, odwr, dorw, odrw, dowr,
>   dwro, rodw, dwor, owrd, rowd, rwdo]

**edit**: changed the `set.each` to a `list.addAll` as it should be faster (and reads a lot easier)

Comment: But how you people have learned about these methods? Want to read Docs?

Comment: Sounds great man!!:):) Started to fall in Love with groovy more :):)

Comment: @Anto: I googled a math formulation of the task + "groovy" word. "Permutations" gave a direct link, and I failed to think of "subsequences" instead of "subsets" :)

Comment: @Victor: I got what i needed!

Comment: @Tim: you could use `set as List` instead of `addAll()`. And after all, I think we could get rid of `inject{}`, using plain `collect{}`. Anyway you were the first to give full answer.

Comment: @Victor Nice! I knew there should be a method of avoiding the `inject`, but I couldn't find it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

`("word" as List).permutations()*.join()` will generate all permutations, not including subsets. Permutations of every possible subset could use [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#Groovy).

**Update:** After reading Tim's answer, I could come up with this:

`("word" as List).subsequences()*.permutations().collect{ it*.join() }.flatten().sort{ it.length() }` (could go without `.sort{...}`)

Comment: Great it worked. But I guess you would have included "*" symbol unknowingly in the front of "join()" method(if i include *,its throwing error). And thanks for your answer too

Comment: Sorry, * should be before dot - it applies the method to every collection item.

Comment: But if I do so, that is Including * then i get a error like this,      "org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/Anto/Groovy/Per.groovy: 1: unexpected token: . @ line 1, column 46.
   ("the" as List).permutations().*join()
"

Comment: It should be `*.join()` not `.*join()`